# Linux Kernel Line Discipline copy_from_user

Tags: c, linux, kernel-module

I have developed a simple line discipline using v4.0.5 of the Linux Kernel, running under Mint Linux.

The tty_ldisc_ops structure looks as follows:

```
static struct tty_ldisc_ops my_ldisc = {
    .owner          = THIS_MODULE,
    .magic          = TTY_LDISC_MAGIC,
    .name           = "my_ldisc",
    .open           = my_open,
    .close          = my_close,
    .read           = my_read,
    .write          = my_write,
    .ioctl          = my_ioctl,
    .poll           = my_poll,
    .receive_buf    = my_receive,
    .write_wakeup   = my_wakeup,
};
```

The module gets added via `insmod my_lkm.ko`. I know it's getting added correct as I've used printk to indicate it and can see the message via `dmesg`. Also, at startup, my userspace application uses ioctl and I have also verified that works via printk.

The problem is, in my_write, copy_from_user always returns a non-zero value indicating that it has failed somehow.

Here is my_write():

```
static ssize_t my_write(struct tty_struct *tty, 
                        struct file *file,
                        const unsigned char *buf, 
                        size_t nr)
{
    int error = 0;
    unsigned char data[MAX]; //MAX is 256 

    if(!my_tty) {
        return -EIO;
    }
    if(nr > MAX) {      //too big       
        return -ENOMEM;
    }
    error = copy_from_user(data,buf,nr);    
    printk("copy_from_user returned %d\n",error);
    //here, error is always equal to nr 
    //(which is 12 in my example application)
    if(error==0) {
        printk("success\n"); //never get here
        return nr;
    }
    return error;
}
```

From what I've researched, copy_from_user eventually calls pa_memcpy which does validation of the pointers being used. That validation is failing, but I can't tell why. I don't know see how *buf and data overlap or would cause a fault.

Output from `uname -a`: `Linux mint-linux 4.0.5-040005-generic #201506061639 SMP Sat Jun 6 16:40:45 UTC 2015 UTC x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

A snippet of the userspace application is:

```
#define OPEN_FLAGS      (O_RDWR|O_NONBLOCK)
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int fd=-1;
    int bytes_written= 0;
    char device="/dev/ttyUSB0";
    unsigned char outbuffer[128]={0};
    fd=open(device,OPEN_FLAGS);
    //set baud rate, etc., switch to my_ldisc (using N_MOUSE)
    outbuffer[0]=0x01;
    outbuffer[1]=0x02;
    outbuffer[2]=0x03;
    outbuffer[3]=0x04;
    outbuffer[4]=0x05;
    outbuffer[5]=0x06;
    outbuffer[6]=0x07;
    outbuffer[7]=0x08;
    outbuffer[8]=0x09;
    outbuffer[9]=0x0A;
    outbuffer[10]=0x0B;
    outbuffer[11]=0x0C;
    bytes_written=write(fd,outbuffer,12);
    while(true) { 
      //...
      sleep(1);
    }
}
```

In addition, any access of buf in my_write causes instability in the VM. Even following the tty driver example in the o'reilly linux drivers book like this:

```
printk(KERN_DEBUG "%s - ", __FUNCTION__);
for(i=0;i<nr;i++)
{       
    printk("%02x ",buf[i]);
}
printk("\n");
```

Following Tsyvarev's advice, I printed the pointer in the user space application and the kernel module. They were different which meant I should access the incoming buffer directly. I used `printf("%p\n",outbuffer);` to do that in user space and the equivalent printk in kernel space.

So, slowing down and testing the module line by line helped me to fix the original problem, which it turns out was a bug in the user space application.

FWIW, the compiler never did give me a warning about the use of __user in the original code. Had it worked the way Tsyvarev suggested it would at compile time, it would have made this a lot easier to track down.

Comment: Forgive my ignorance but... is this correct?: `unsigned char outbuffer[128]={0};` Wouldn't this define a 1-byte array instead of a 128-byte array? Does it make any difference if you don't initialize that array and leave its definition only as `unsigned char outbuffer[128];` ?

Comment: I don't think it makes a difference. Based on your comment, I've tried it both ways to test my sanity and it failed both ways.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unlike to [.write](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/fs.h?v=4.0#L1542) method of `struct file_operations`, which accepts pointer to *user* data, [.write](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/tty_driver.h?v=4.0#L260) method for `struct tty_operations` accepts **pointer to kernel data**, and these data shold be accessed via usual methods such as `memcpy` or even directly.

Modern kernel uses `__user` attribute for mark *user-space* data, and this attribute is checked (at compile time) when data is accessed. So having compiler warnings enabled will reveal usage of the data with incorrect origin.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. However, any access to the buf variable fails. Attempting to access buf directly causes the machine to lock. An additional note is that this same module, using the __user declaration for buf works fine using copy_from_user in v3.11.

Comment: Please see my edits. Adding or removing __user makes no difference and either declaration produces no compiler warnings.

Comment: Probably, there are errors in the other parts of you module. Absence of compiler warnings seems suspicious: your `my_write` function doesn't return value at the end, and compiler should definitely warn about this. Are you set compiler flags via `ccflags-y:= -Wall` or other way?

Comment: I just added -Wall to the compiler flags.

Comment: `I just added -Wall to the compiler flags.` - **How exactly** you do this? There is no direct calling of the compiler when build kernel module.

Comment: I followed your advice and added the line `ccflags-y := -Wall` to the Makefile. No compiler warnings are produced.

Comment: @Coleman, you cannot use `copy_from_user` function in this context, as the user pointer of `copy_from_user` is a pointer in user space data (this is the reason to have a function to pass the data from user to kernel context).  The answer just tells you not to use that function, as in the context of line disciplines, no user data is concerned.  This is what this response says, and not a recommendation to overcome compiler warnings or using `__user` attributes to overcome the compiler warnings.

Comment: @Coleman: You can easly check, whether `buf` points to user space or kernel space: print address of the buffer both in the kernel driver and user program. If addresses are same, then `buf` is user space buffer and should be accessed using `copy_from_user`, otherwise `buf` is kernel space buffer, and should be accessed directly.

Comment: Here are the results of printing the addresses. As you can see, they are different. In my user space application: `buf=0x7ffefbbd2210` and in the module: `buf=ffff88003596e000`. I used `printf("buf=%p",(void*)outbuffer);` in the application and `printk("buf=%p",(void*)buf);` in the module.

Comment: So, based on your comment, this means I should be able to access buf directly in my module and copy_from_user is not needed, correct?

Comment: `I should be able to access buf directly in my module and copy_from_user is not needed, correct?` - Yes, `copy_from_user` is not needed here. Another method for determine "area" for address - "very high" addresses (started with several `f`) are belong to kernel.